# How to add a timer in views?

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I have created a view which displays a list of product in table grid formate with four rows. I have fields related to the product like image,price,descriptions and so on. Now I want to create a field which should display the  discount time left for each product. I tried to use jQuery countdown timer module to implement this but it didn't work. Can any one suggest which module I can use to create a timer field in Druapl7.

Comment: Could you show how your jQuery implementation lookes like.

Comment: I have just installed the Jquery timer module from http://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown and I configured this module with a start date and end date. I am able to create a block with this not as specific field in my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track.

Check out this issue comment: http://drupal.org/node/685956#comment-4412688

It links to a GitHub repo, from which you can find a fork at https://github.com/blackice2999/jquery_countdown/tree/7.x-1.x that appears to contain a Drupal 7 port.

Try that.

Comment: Thanks a lot wizonesolution. I was able to partially fix my problem.